# ASP Grid View, predifine the row height size

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, gridview, dynamic-data

I have a Asp Gridview with two dynamic columns. One column will display set of characters (description) and other column is for displaying Image. 
I just want to limit this description Grid row height.

```
<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True"
                  AllowPaging="True" GridLines="None" onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label_dynamicDes" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("description") %>'></asp:Label> <br/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="picpath" ControlStyle-Width='200px'>
                <ControlStyle Width="200px"></ControlStyle>
            </asp:ImageField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_dynamic" runat="server">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

</div>
```

How can I control the Height of GridView row size? I can not do it in Code behind. Please help me with some css function to predefine the size of dynamic row?

Answer (score 3):

You can set `RowStyle` and `AlternatingRowStyle` from either code behind or in the markup. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) for more details.

**Edit:**

You can either set the `RowStyle-CssClass` in the markup like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True"
AllowPaging="True" GridLines="None" onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"
RowStyle-CssClass="my-table-row-style">
```

Set it in the code behind like this:

```
GridView1.RowStyle.CssClass = "my-table-row-style";
```

Or just do it purely with CSS like this:

```
#GridView1 td
{
    height: 90px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you don't want the height of the row to be greater than the height of the image (assuming 90px). You could put a div with fixed height in the TemplateField and set the height

```
   <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>

       <div style="height:90px; overflow:auto">
        <asp:Label ID="Label_dynamicDes" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("description") %>'></asp:Label>
       </div>

    </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

When the description is more than the height, the div will have a scrollbar because of `overflow:auto`. You can also have `overflow:scroll`